# Best Kids Triathlon Bikes

Tags: racing, triathlon, children

What are some of the best kids (8-15) triathlon bikes for racing?

Comment: Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic because they tend to become obsolete quickly.

Comment: Gidday and welcome to SE Bicycles.  Please browse the tour to learn how this stack is different to regular old chatty forums.   http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/tour

Answer (score 1):

I know we're not supposed to answer questions that are off topic, but I can't post this in a comment.

*Don't Spoil It for your kid*

[image: Filthy Casuals!]

Caption: "Filthy Casuals!  Get a real bike!"

Comment: I just realised this poor kid has "lightweight" wheels, which are probably worth more than all 10 of my bikes combined.

Answer (score 1):

The one that fits.

You've got a wide range there. I don't know of a tri-bike that's going to fit an 8 year old. By 15 the kid should be ready for an adult bike. Somewhere in between an extra small road bike is going to be the best option. AFAIK, 43cm is as small as you'll get. A search for 43 cm road bike will get you on your way.